# Show that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^2 $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Show that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^2 $ is continuous

My attempt. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed but arbitrary.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta := \min\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{4|a|}\}$

Then, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-a| <\delta$, we have:

$$|x^2 - a^2| = |x-a||x+a| = |x-a||x-a + 2a| \leq|x-a|(|x-a| + 2|a|) \leq \delta^2 + 2\delta|a|\leq \epsilon$$

Hence, $f$ is continuous at $a$ and because $a$ is arbitrary it follows that $f$ is continuous on its domain, as desired.

Is this correct? (not a duplicate btw, I have my own proof with another choice of delta than other proofs)

Comment: $a=0$ may be a problem with your $\delta$.

Comment: Seems to work.  If there's an error it's mechanical and minor.  That is definitely the correct idea.

Comment: ... or $a = 0$ may be an issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof looks good. The only issue I can see is that your definition of $\delta$ has an undefined expression in it if $a=0$. This should be pretty easy to fix, though.

Depending on what your instructor is looking for, you might want to make explicit why the two terms in your penultimate expression are each less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: Good to know, I can fix this by adding 1 in the denumerator! So, $\delta := \min\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|+1)}\}$ would work?

Comment: Indeed, that looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.